# What will be a correct data structure for questionnaire

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, user-interface, data-structures

I am trying to develop a questionnaire where questions are dependent on answers, 
What will be correct UI data structure to hold the questions and questionnaire flow?

Sorry if this unclear, Would like to eliminate some parts of the UI based on the answers, so i need some kind of data structure in Java script so I can dynamically modify the html based on the answers, so the question is how to bring the data as json to the page, and how to hold it in JS and eliminate some parts of the UI based on the json and answers.

```
1 What is your name?_______
2 Did you ever code in java?___Y/N____
     3 <Question should appear only if answer is yes> How many years? ____
     4 <Question should appear only if answer is no> Did you ever code using any programming language? ____
5 Select occupation 
        a Developer
        b Project manager
6 <Question should appear only if answer to 5 is b> years experience in project management ________
```

Comment: most obvious answer would be a BST for each tree of conditional questions.

Comment: @Paul: That would be a binary tree, not a binary search tree.

Comment: @JimMischel sry, got the two mixed up. I meant binary tree

Comment: Using a graph structure (e. g. a tree) to capture all preconditions might not work if we have more questions or more preconditions than in the example provided by OP if we don't want to have the same question appear multiple times in our graph.

Comment: Please do not change the programminglanguage of the question again. Because me and Ie_m make work for nothing if you change the language again. I guess this is a unfair method of collect reputation.

Comment: Peter please put the old solution again so i will split the reputation, sorry about that!

Comment: what is ui-data structure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say we only have the following constraints:

- You want to define each question exactly once
- A question can depend on any answer of any previously asked question

Then I propose the following generic solution:

```js
// Each question has an id, a text and a condition depending on previous answers:
var questions = [
  {id: "name", text: "What is your name?"},
  {id: "code-java", text: "Did you ever code in Java?"},
  {id: "code-java-years", text: "How many years?", condition: answers => answers["code-java"] == "yes"},
  {id: "code-other", text: "Did you ever code using any programming language?", condition: answers => answers["code-java"] == "no"},
  {id: "occupation", text: "Select occupation?"},
  {id: "experience-management-years", text: "Years experience in project management?", condition: answers => answers["occupation"] == "Project manager"}
]

// Ask all questions whose conditions evaluate to true and collect the answers:
var answers = {};
questions.forEach(question => {
  if (!question.condition || question.condition(answers)) {
    answers[question.id] = prompt(question.text);
  }
});

console.log(answers);
```

You probably would want to add more details to each questions such as a validation function, a type (boolean, text, selection, ...) etc.

If you need to store and transfer your questions as plain JSON, you would need to replace your condition functions with a data structure such as `conditions: [{id: "code-java", operator: "equals", value: "yes"}]` which is evaluated by

```
operators = {
  'equals': (answer, value) => answer == value,
  'regex': (answer, value) => new RegExp(value).test(answer),
  ...
}

conditions.every(condition => operators[condition.operator](answers[condition.id], condition.value))
```